# How to get respond.js to work with Bootstrap 3.3.7. in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I have searched around to make this work but the problem remains, in IE8 the Bootstrap grid is in a total mess, and the page is completely unreadable. I have a local copy of bootstrap.min.css, and this is how my head section looks like:

What am I missing here..?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="html5shiv-master/src/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="Respond-master/dest/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

This is at the end od the body:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do the two script files that you're calling to exist locally (in your development environment)? In IE8 and below, they should be loaded just fine. In your JavaScript console, do you have any errors (namely 404 errors if the files aren't there?)

Comment: Yes I got this(I have no idea what is the Bootstrap's JavaScript error, jQuery is included). And how do you mean in the 'development environment'...? They are in folder(so I have downloaded them, it's not CDN) Invalid character  respond.js, line 1 character 1
  Expected identifier  jquery.js, line 3873 character 4
  Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery  bootstrap.min.js, line 6 character 31

Comment: Your console is showing any errors regarding the loading of those files? You also have to be aware that jquery versions > 2.x, doesn't support IE8 [link](http://blog.jquery.com/2015/04/28/jquery-1-11-3-and-2-1-4-released-ios-fail-safe-edition/)

Comment: @CarlosCrespo Those are the errors that I get, and I get the same thing with jQuery 1.10.1...

Comment: You need to load Jquery before respond and html5. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CarlosCrespo yes I have, same thing happens :/

Comment: That's weird. The only thing that comes to my mind, considering this situation, is that the browser is caching the old version of your page, and, therefore, loading the version in which jquery is loaded after those scripts. I would recommend you to clear the cache and retry =/

Comment: @CarlosCrespo I know it's frustrating. I have deleted all the cache and still get the same issue. So now I load jQuery 1.10.1 before html5 and respond, still the same. Is this code entered properly, I mean this part has to be commented out like so, right?   <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="html5shiv-master/src/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="Respond-master/dest/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Yes! I have a project with the same situation, and everything works fine. I load jquery 1.11.1 before respond and html5shiv, and I use the same conditional comment for compatibility mode. And I also load jquery 3.1.1 when IE is in higher versions, with <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->